# How to translate one string from one locale into another using FastGettext?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, gettext

I use [FastGettext](https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext) in my Rails application.

I need a particular string translated into every single `FastGettext.available_locales` in my application.

How to do that?

<del>PS: I couldn't find the solution with I18n either.</del> (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can do something like that with I18n :

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |loc|
  # do something with...
  I18n.t(keypath, :locale => loc)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Katen! So you partially solved my question, but I actually need to perform the translation with Gettext (or FastGettext).